# Find the parent element with the least physical space occupied by child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

When given multiple container `<divs>`, each with a number of child `<divs>` of varying dimensions, I want to work out which container has the least **area covered** by child elements.

```
<div class="container" id="first">
    <div class="small">This is a message</div>
    <div class="medium">This is a message</div>
    <div class="large">This is a message</div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="second">
    <div class="large">This is a message</div>
    <div class="large">This is a message</div>
    <div class="large">This is a message</div>
</div>
```

Example styles:

```
.container { width: 1000px; height: 1000px }

.small { width: 100px; height: 50px }
.medium { width: 200px; height: 100px }
.large { width: 400px; height: 200px }
```

Background: Users can post a message (child `<div>`) to a notice board (parent container `<div>`) and I want to highlight the "most empty" notice board.

I just need help with the logic, I can probably code it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the area by multiplying the element's [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) by its [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight).

---

Declare two variables, `smallest`, for storing the smallest element, and `smallestArea`, for storing the area of the smallest element.

Then, select all elements with the `container` class and loop through each one. Check if the area (calculated by multiplying the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` of the element's children) is smaller than `smallestArea`. If it is, we know it is smaller than the current value of `smallest`, so we assign the current element to `smallest` and the area to `smallestArea`.

After iterating through all the elements, `smallest` will be the element with the smallest area.

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

var smallest;
var smallestArea;

containers.forEach(e => {
  let area = [...e.children].reduce((a,b) => a += b.offsetHeight * b.offsetWidth, 0);
  if (!smallestArea || area < smallestArea) {
    smallest = e;
    smallestArea = area;
  }
})

console.log(smallest)
```

```css
.container{width:1000px;height:1000px}.small{width:100px;height:50px}.medium{width:200px;height:100px}.large{width:400px;height:200px}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="first">
  <div class="small">This is a message</div>
  <div class="medium">This is a message</div>
  <div class="large">This is a message</div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="second">
  <div class="large">This is a message</div>
  <div class="large">This is a message</div>
  <div class="large">This is a message</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Great solution. I wasn't aware of `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the container that has the least area covered by child elements using [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) and [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

To demonstrate I've added another container that has 3 chidren of `small`, `small` and `medium`.

```js
const [container, size] = [...document.querySelectorAll(".container")].reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let currentContainerArea = 0;
  for (let child of curr.children) {
    currentContainerArea += child.offsetWidth * child.offsetHeight;
  }
  if (currentContainerArea < acc[1]) {
    acc[0] = curr;
    acc[1] = currentContainerArea;
  }
  return acc;
}, [null, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER]);

console.log(size)
console.log(container)
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.small {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.medium {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.large {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="first">
  <div class="small">This is a message</div>
  <div class="medium">This is a message</div>
  <div class="large">This is a message</div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="second">
  <div class="large">This is a message</div>
  <div class="large">This is a message</div>
  <div class="large">This is a message</div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="third">
  <div class="small">This is a message</div>
  <div class="small">This is a message</div>
  <div class="medium">This is a message</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also a great answer. Thank you